# MobileAppTracker Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:

Tags: ios

MobileAppTracker ios SDK

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:


Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:

     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SKPaymentQueue", referenced from:    

     objc-class-ref in MobileAppTracker(MATStoreKitDelegate.o)  

     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SKProductsRequest", referenced from:

     objc-class-ref in MobileAppTracker(MATStoreKitDelegate.o)

     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CTTelephonyNetworkInfo", referenced from:

     objc-class-ref in MobileAppTracker(MATSettings.o)

     "_ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierLandscape", referenced from:

     l018 in MobileAppTracker(MATTracker.o)

     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ADBannerView", referenced from:

      objc-class-ref in MobileAppTracker(MATTracker.o)

    "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ADClient", referenced from:

      objc-class-ref in MobileAppTracker(MATTracker.o)

    "_ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait", referenced from:

      l018 in MobileAppTracker(MATTracker.o)

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: You need to add frameworks like `StoreKit`, `iAd` and `Security`.

Comment: I use MobileAppTracker ios SDK , When using the SDK ，Xcode wrong  . When not using , Xcode normal.  How would I do?

Comment: Yes I know you used `MobileAppTracker` but these are supported frameworks you need to add to make it work, see here for setup instructions http://developers.mobileapptracking.com/ios-sdk/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this. Go to,

> Your Project->Build Phases->Link Binary With Libraries

press + button and add iAd.framework , Security.framework and StoreKit.framework. Clean and Build your project.

Comment: Add the following additional frameworks to your project:
AdSupport.framework
CoreTelephony.framework
iAd.framework
MobileCoreServices.framework
StoreKit.framework
SystemConfiguration.framework                        Thank you very much!!!

Comment: In my case the issue was with `ADClient`. Importing `iAd.framework` solved it.

Comment: For me adding just StoreKit.framework was enough. Thanks!